# How can I subtract an array from a single data frame column?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have two "vectors" of numbers where I would like to subtract one from the other. My problem is that one of them is an array of a list:

```
array([[ 796.24475 ],
      [ -17.138123],
      [ 164.9989  ],
      ...,
      [-469.85388 ],
      [-762.1892  ],
      [-451.34702 ]], dtype=float32)
```

whereas the other one is a column of a pandas data frame:

```
0       831.871558
21       26.070256
25      199.351116
28      861.052529
35      113.232070
           ...    
9440   -163.200046
9448   -893.619023
9449   -439.174531
9451   -795.033901
9461   -413.469417
Name: electricity, Length: 1895, dtype: float64
```

They both have the same amount of data points and the error I get when I try to subtract one from the other is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 636, in __array_ufunc__
    self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs
  File "pandas\_libs\ops_dispatch.pyx", line 91, in pandas._libs.ops_dispatch.maybe_dispatch_ufunc_to_dunder_op
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 502, in wrapper
    return _construct_result(left, result, index=left.index, name=res_name)
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 475, in _construct_result
    out = left._constructor(result, index=index)
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 305, in __init__
    data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure=True)
  File "C:\Projects\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 482, in sanitize_array
    raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simpliest is selecting for 1d array (lengths od DataFrame and array has to be same):

```
df['electricity'] - arr[:, 0]
```

Another idea, thank you @timgeb is use [`numpy.squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
df['electricity'] - arr.squeeze()
```

Comment: Alternatively subtract `arr.squeeze()`.

Comment: I think `DataFrame.squeeze` is more like `numpy.ndarray.item`.

Comment: @timgeb - I think working similar, 1 column DataFrame convert to Series

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to convert your array to a pandas series.
(If it is a numpy array, you could do it as below)

```
series = pd.Series(np_array)
```

(Ensure to reshape the np.array first if necessary)

Then you can subtract this series from the column in pandas dataframe as below:

```
df['col_name'] - series
```